# Importing .xlxs into Oracle PL/SQL database

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

I have a problem with VBA importing data to Oracle PL/SQL database. I have this script:

```
sql = "insert into my_table (Name, Surname,Phone,Email,Date, time_1,Time_2,Note, Source, Change,State,Result) 
       values ( '" & Cells(cellNumber, 1) & "' , '" & Cells(cellNumber, 2) & "' ,  '" & Cells(cellNumber, 3) & "' ,  '" & Cells(cellNumber, 4) & "', to_date('" & Cells(cellNumber, 5) & "'," & "'DD.MM.YYYY')," & " to_date('" & Cells(cellNumber, 6) & "'," & "' HH24:MI:SS')," & " to_date('" & Cells(cellNumber, 7) & "'," & "' HH24:MI:SS'),"  & "to_date('" & Cells(cellNumber, 8) & "'," & "'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , '" & Cells(cellNumber, 9) & "' ,  '" & Cells(cellNumber, 10) & "' ,  '" & Cells(cellNumber, 11) & "' ,  '" & Cells(cellNumber, 12) & " ') "## Heading ##
```

Everything is OK except `time_1` and `time_2`. The format in Excel is `HH24:MI:SS` and VBA transforms it to single number such as: `0,0754234`. 
I need to preserve the `HH24:MI:SS` format.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Some education: PL/SQL is a programming language from Oracle, with which you can access Oracle databases. SQL is a query language for accessing relational databases. You are trying to import data into an Oracle database, using SQL. PL/SQL has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sql = "insert into mytable (Name, Surname,Phone,Email,Date,
>   time_1,Time_2,Note, Source, Change,State,Result)  values ( '" &
>   Cells(cellNumber, 1) & "' , '" & Cells(cellNumber, 2) & "' ,  '" &
>   Cells(cellNumber, 3) & "' ,  '" & Cells(cellNumber, 4) & "',
>   to_date('" & Cells(cellNumber, 5) & "'," & "'DD.MM.YYYY'),'" &
>   CStr(Format(Cells(cellNumber, 6), "Long time")) & "','" &
>   CStr(Format(Cells(cellNumber, 7), "Long time")) & "', to_date('" &
>   Cells(cellNumber, 8) & "'," & "'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , '" &
>   Cells(cellNumber, 9) & "' ,  '" & Cells(cellNumber, 10) & "' ,  '" &
>   Cells(cellNumber, 11) & "' ,  '" & Cells(cellNumber, 12) & " ') "